# PHP text file has numbers in front when downloaded + unexpected file name

Tags: php, fopen, readfile, fwrite, fclose

```
<?php
$file = fopen("testing.txt","w");
$txt = "Who let the dogs out?! \r\n";
echo fwrite($file, $txt);

header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file.txt");
header("Content-Type: text/plain; ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile('testing.txt');
?>
```

**First issue:** I read on the PHP website (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) that there could be issues with line-*ending*, but when `testing.txt` has been downloaded and is opened, the following line appears with some numbers added in front:

`25Who let the dogs out?!`

**Second issue:** I noticed the file name is `Resource id #3.txt` instead of `testing.txt`. A Google search reveals that that error message is commonly associated with MySQL/PHP, but it is only PHP for my case.

Comment: instead of `echo fwrite($file, $txt);` just write `fwrite($file, $txt);`  and `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.txt");`

Comment: also, you are using `$file` for the file name, that's a file resource and as expected, you get its string representation as your file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it is because you have this line in your code

```
echo fwrite($file, $txt);
```

Try this code

```
fwrite($file, $txt);
```

and correct this

```
$filename = 'testing.txt';
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.txt");
```

Comment: Okay this is pure embarrassment on my end. Can't believe the solution is that simple (I thought it is something to do with CR)!

Also I *just* noticed that I omitted fclose() by accident.